# JQuery onclick function to call a function in PHP via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function, onclick

Creating function increment the session value called clicks every time someone clicks a button, the php works perfectly fine, but failing to call it via AJAX.

JQuery:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'resources/ajax/addclick.php',
        success: function(output) {
            alert(output);
        }
    });
});
```

php: addclicks.php

```
<?php 
require_once("../config.php");

function click(){
    $_SESSION['clicks'] ++;
}
?>
```

php: config.php

```
session_id();
session_start();

$id = session_id();

if (!isset($_SESSION['started'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tokyo");
    $_SESSION['started'] = date("h:i:s a");
    $_SESSION['date'] = date("Y/m/d");
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['clicks'])) {
    $_SESSION['clicks'] = 0;
}
```

html button:

```
<form class="button" method="post">
  <button class="button" id="button" type="submit">Click 
   me</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Please show us _all_ relevant PHP code. How are you calling the function? Do you have `session_start()`? Probably a typo, but your ajax request is calling `addclick.php` (singular) while you've written that the PHP code is in `addclicks.php` (plural).

Comment: I've addded some more of the code, hope this helps! Thank you for your time

Comment: You've added more code from a file we don't see get included anywhere. Please show us all the code in the file you're actually calling (addclick.php)

Comment: It has been included, sorry about the bad post.

Comment: You never actually call your `click()`-function anywhere which is why the code in it won't get executed.

Comment: So i'm supposed to call it? I thought ajax took care of that

Comment: Ajax just makes a request to the PHP-file. That's it. It's like any other request. Then it's up to your code to do what you want it to. If you want to run functions, then you need to call them yourself in your PHP-file.

Comment: tried removing the functions and just <?php require_once("../config.php");
  $_SESSION['clicks'] ++;
 ?> still doesn't work sadly

Comment: If you're expecting your ajax request to get a response, you need to output it in your PHP code, or the response will be empty.

Comment: tried that as well, with an echo and print, I'm not sure if this is what you meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("button").click(function(){   
  $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "addclick.php",
  data: { add: 1 }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( msg );
  });
});
```

And your php most be like this

```
<?php
$_SESSION['clicks'] = $_SESSION['clicks'] + $_POST['add'];

echo $_SESSION['clicks'];
?>
```

Your html doesn't need form tag, al least you want to prevent submit

```
<button class="button" id="button" type="submit">Click 
   me</button>
```

Comment: Sadly still not working. Thanks for the snippets though

Comment: Can you share how are you implementing this?

Comment: basically implementet exactly what you wrote here, but changed the path of the addclick to the correct one

Comment: Check edit i made

Comment: still not doing anything at all sadly

Comment: Code is ok, maybe you are doing something wrong, maybe you didn't implement jquery, or addclick.php path is wrong, review your code.

Comment: It worked out, the cdn was placed under, after i placed it above it worked. THANKS!